# Unable to ssh to Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I used to log in to the instance through GCE web UI by clicking "Open in web browser".

Recently I try to log in the instance using the same way, but the window just keep showing "connecting" and didn't do anything.

I try ssh from google cloud shell. And what I get is:

```
USERNAME@cloudshell:~ (voltaic-phalanx-786)$ gcloud compute ssh --zone "asia-east1-c" "newforum" --project "voltaic-phalanx-786" --ssh-flag="-vvv"
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname X.X.X.X is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to X.X.X.X [X.X.X.X] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 0
debug1: identity file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to X.X.X.X:22 as 'USERNAME'
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.xxx
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/USERNAME/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from compute.xxx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-grou
p14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-grou
p14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
USERNAME@X.X.X.X: Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I try restart the instance. The last few lines of serial port output is:

```
Apr  6 14:14:45 newforum systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Apr  6 14:14:46 newforum GCEMetadataScripts[1575]: 2021/04/06 14:14:46 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 20201217.02-0ubuntu1~18.04.0).
Apr  6 14:14:46 newforum GCEMetadataScripts[1575]: 2021/04/06 14:14:46 GCEMetadataScripts: Found startup-script in metadata.
Apr  6 14:14:46 newforum GCEMetadataScripts[1575]: 2021/04/06 14:14:46 GCEMetadataScripts: startup-script: Skipping adding existing rule
Apr  6 14:14:46 newforApr  6 14:14:46 newforum systemd[1]: Started Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.
Apr  6 14:14:46 newforum systemd[1]: Startup finished in 6.585s (kernel) + 17.727s (userspace) = 24.313s.


Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS newforum ttyS0

newforum login: Apr  6 14:15:14 newforum snapd[1048]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60506->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
Apr  6 14:15:16 newforum snapd[1048]: daemon.go:589: gracefully waiting for running hooks
Apr  6 14:15:16 newforum snapd[1048]: daemon.go:591: done waiting for running hooks
Apr  6 14:15:16 newforum snapd[1048]: daemon stop requested to wait for socket activation
Apr  6 14:29:37 newforum systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Apr  6 14:29:37 newforum systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

And I still can't log into the instance. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your post might be deleted since sensitive information was shared and it might have been flagged already. To minimize risks to your project I recommend you to speed up the deletion process (If you just edit the post the information is kept in the edit history).

That being said, please check the following:

Reading through your logs I noticed the error `Permission denied (publickey)` which is commonly attributed to OS login activated at instance or project level.

Follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) to disable OS Login if enabled, as explained in the warning for this step:

**Caution: Enabling OS Login on instances disables metadata-based SSH key configurations on those instances. Disabling OS Login restores SSH keys that you have configured in project or instance metadata.**

You can also try to enable Serial Port access to this instance and [troubleshoot the SSH connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) from here, the steps are as follow:

1. Enabling access for a VM instance

- In the Google Cloud Console, go to the VM instances page.
- Go to the VM instances page
- Click the instance you want to enable access for.
- Click Edit.
- Under the Remote access section, toggle the Enable connecting to serial ports checkbox.
- Save your changes.

2. Adding a startup script to create a local user.

- In the Google Cloud Console, go to the VM instances page.
- Go to the VM instances page
- Click the instance for which you want to add a startup script. The instance details page displays.
- From the instance details page, complete the following steps:
  Click the Edit button at the top of the page.
- Under Custom metadata, click Add item.
- Add your startup script using one of the following keys (you should replace variables on caps like USERNAME and PASSWORD):

```
Key: startup-script

Value:

#! /bin/bash
sudo useradd USERNAME; echo -e "PASSWORD\nPASSWORD" | passwd USERNAME | echo 'USERNAME ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

- With this startup script you will create a local user on linux OS with sudo privileges.
- Stop/Start the VM

3. Connecting to a serial console

- In the Google Cloud Console, go to the VM instances page.
- Go to the VM instances page
- Click the instance you want to connect to.
- Under Remote access, click Connect to the serial console to connect on the default port (port 1).
- Login using the USERNAME and PASSWORD you provided on the script.
- Once logged in just type “bash” command to start the bash terminal like when accessed via SSH.
- Restart SSH service:

```
$ sudo service sshd status
$ sudo service sshd restart
```

- After restarting, try to connect via SSH again.

As a recovery method, if you are able to create a new instance and connect to it with no problem, you can [create a Snapshot from the disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#create_zonal_snapshot) of the affected instance and [create a new instance from it](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) or you can [detach the affected disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/detach-reattach-boot-disk#detach_disk) and [attach it to a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) to transfer the information.

It would also be helpful if you **collect and share your logs:**

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the VM instance details find section `Logs` and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
2. Reboot your VM instance (if possible).
3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.
4. **If you found errors/warning related to disk space** You can try to resize it according to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) or follow this article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance).
5. If you require more help, share the full log by using [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Disable OS Login didn't allow me to ssh into the instance.

Comment: I can create a new instance, and I can ssh into it with no problem.

Comment: The full log after the last reboot is here: https://pastebin.com/Eu6Rg1Wx And I found some error about docker failed to start container. Is that relative?

Comment: If OS Login was enabled, I'm pretty sure that is the reason why you could not connect to the instance since OS Login disables metadata-based SSH key configurations, after OS Login is disabled, you need to wait a couple of minutes for the changes to propagate before attempting the SSH connection again.

I was unable to find anything out of place in the logs, I'll modify my answer to add another troubleshoot method and a recovery process in case the issue persists after that.

Comment: The links in your 4. seem to be the same?

Comment: Not quite the same, in the step above it is explained how to create a VM from a disk snapshot and the step you are mentioning is to mount the disk to a new instance.

Comment: It acts the same way when I create new instance with snapshot. I can enable and connect via Serial Port access to the instance, but it requires login information for further manipulation.

Comment: The steps to add a local user to interact with the instance via Serial port were added to my response, also another recovery method so you can at least recover your information from the affected disk.

Comment: OK, I can login into the instance via serial port. Is there something I should check out about the instance?

Comment: And I attach the disk with new instance. But I stall cannot ssh into the new instance,  so I attach the disk back to the original instance.

Comment: Due to the complexity of this case, I recommend you to use [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/prod_issue) to open a Google Cloud Platform Support Question, you can include all the troubleshooting already performed or directly reference this post.

Comment: If the information was helpful please don't forget to up vote or accept the answer.

Comment: I check the status of sshd. It is running normally. Then restart sshd, but I still cannot connect to the instance. It seems the ssh keys can be transfer into the instance by Google.

Comment: At some point you mentioned that you can login into the instance via serial port, if this still true, login again and follow the [troubleshoot the SSH connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) document, otherwise, I recommend you to continue working with the GCP support team on this.